# Kafka streams JSON-POJO deserialization exception

Tags: json, apache-kafka, deserialization, apache-kafka-streams, json-deserialization

```
    ERROR org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.LogAndFailExceptionHandler - Exception caught during Deserialization, taskId: 0_1, topic: SourceTopic, partition: 1, offset: 0
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "before" (class StreamsApplication$Person), not marked as ignorable (0 known properties: ])
 at [Source: [B@19ac162c; line: 1, column: 12] (through reference chain: Person["before"])
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "before" (class StreamsApplication$Person), not marked as ignorable (0 known properties: ])
 at [Source: [B@19ac162c; line: 1, column: 12] (through reference chain: Person["before"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException.from(UnrecognizedPropertyException.java:62)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnknownProperty(DeserializationContext.java:833)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer.handleUnknownProperty(StdDeserializer.java:1096)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.handleUnknownProperty(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1467)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.handleUnknownVanilla(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1445)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:282)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:140)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3789)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2920)
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaJsonDeserializer.deserialize(KafkaJsonDeserializer.java:75)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Deserializer.deserialize(Deserializer.java:60)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.SourceNode.deserializeValue(SourceNode.java:55)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordDeserializer.deserialize(RecordDeserializer.java:66)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordQueue.updateHead(RecordQueue.java:176)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordQueue.addRawRecords(RecordQueue.java:112)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.PartitionGroup.addRawRecords(PartitionGroup.java:185)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.addRecords(StreamTask.java:865)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.TaskManager.addRecordsToTasks(TaskManager.java:938)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runOnce(StreamThread.java:640)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:551)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:510)
2756 [MyID-8bbe36da-883c-48eb-8b86-cad4a3acb5e2-StreamThread-1] ERROR org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread - stream-thread [MyID-8bbe36da-883c-48eb-8b86-cad4a3acb5e2-StreamThread-1] Encountered the following exception during processing and the thread is going to shut down: 
org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: Deserialization exception handler is set to fail upon a deserialization error. If you would rather have the streaming pipeline continue after a deserialization error, please set the default.deserialization.exception.handler appropriately.
```

This is the exception I am facing while deserializing JSON record in kafka topic in kafka streams. JSON record is nested and is as shown:

```
{
"before": {
  "id": 1,
  "name": "abc"
},
"after": {
  "id": 1,
  "name": "xyz"
}
```

}

and POJO class defined is:

```
public static class Person{
        before before;
        after after;
    }
    public static class before{
        public int id;
        public String name;
    }
    public static class after{
        public int id;
        public String name;
    }
```

Please tell me where I am mistaken and how I can improve this. Thank you.

Comment: The name in json "before" does not match the `Person` field name "beforeClass"

Comment: Same error even after changes are made, please  check changes in question and guide

Comment: Class names in java should be camel case - it should begin with uppercase letter.
`
public static class Before{
       public int id;
       public String name;
}`

Comment: resolved it, it just needs getter setter and those subclasses to be part of it

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static class Person{
        private Before before;
        private After after;
        
        public Before getBefore(){
            return before;
        }
        public After getAfter(){
            return after;
        }
        public static class Before{
            public int id;
            public String name;

        }
        public static class After{
            public int id;
            public String name;

        }
    }
```

Changes which I made in POJO person class, it helped in resolving my issue.